# Adding updated arraylist to an arraylist of arraylist replaces previous values

Tags: java, collections

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> out = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    for(int i =1;i<=2;i++) {
        out.add(i);
        result.add(out);
    }

    System.out.println(result.toString());
}
```

Why is the output : 
[[1, 2], [1, 2]] when it should be [[1], [1, 2]]

Comment: You are not creating a copy of `out`. You just modify the same object.

Comment: It's the core idea behind OOP. You just add two _references_ of the same list.

Comment: So how do you achieve the output as [[1], [1, 2]] ?

Comment: use `result.add(new ArrayList(out));` which should add a clone of the arraylist `out`.  [ArrayList API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are modifying the same reference of out, it gets reflected everywhere. in order to freeze your list at a particular point, you need to create a clone of it and add that new list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
ArrayList<Integer> out = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
for(int i =1;i<=2;i++) {
    out.add(i);
    ArrayList<Integer> freeze = new ArrayList<Integer>(out);
    result.add(freeze);
}

System.out.println(result.toString());
}
```